# Hover div's direct children style (only CSS)

Tags: css

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pegspksp/)

I want to apply style to `p` children of `div [class*="high-"]` when hovering (any div starting with high-), but not all `p` children, only the one inside the hovered parent. If not jQuery needed, better.

HTML:

```
    <div class="high-venas">
      <p><strong>Venas y varices</strong><br>
         <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></p>
   </div>

    <div class="high-cirugiaCalvicie">
      <p><strong>Cirujía calvicie</strong><br>
         <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nonummy nibh </span></p>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
#highlights p {
    background-color: white;
    opacity:0.7;
}
```

As i've tried these examples down here **with no result**, I think this could be caused by the selector, maybe it is not identifiying when mouse hovers a div starting with "high-":

```
div [class*="high-"]:hover > div > p {
    opacity:1;
}
```

---

```
[class*="high-"]:hover > div > p {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried? div[class*="high-"]:hover p {opacity:1; }

Comment: Both your selectors are wrong – in the first one you have a space between the element and the attribute selector (so that looks for an element with that class on a _child_ element of a div), and your second one tries to find a div first underneath the element with that class, which there isn’t in your actual element structure.

Comment: Live demo added on post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set a white space between the `div` and the attribute selector `[something]`. Also, there's no intermediary div between the "high-" one and the `p`, so remove it. It would be like this, instead:

```
div[class*="high-"]:hover > p {
    opacity:1;
}
```

A white space, on CSS selectors means a *descendand*, so you were looking for a element with the attribute, inside a div...

**EDIT**

In the provided fiddle you have another problem, due to selectors specificity. Id selectors have priority over attribute ones, so your first `p` selector, as it was subjected to an id selector `#highlights p {` has priority over the `:hover` one. To fix it, use the id selector on the hover rule too:

[**Updated JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pegspksp/2/)

```
#highlights div[class*="high-"]:hover > p {

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but these changes do not solve the problem.. nothing happens. Ill make a jsFiddle to try to reproduce the problem

Comment: @Biomehanika, use the SO's code snippet... (Ctrl + M)

Comment: Very grateful. I'll tick in 1 minute.

Answer (score 1):

the css code does not work because the p tag is not within another div.

use:

```
[class*="high-"]:hover > p {
    opacity:1;
    background: #F00;
}
```

to have only the p element within the hovered high-* element highlighted.

Comment: true, I seem to have red something different, my bad... corrected